# College/Teen movie where they drug a hot teachers chocolate then watch her through a two-way mirror

Tags: identify-this-movie

I've been racking my brain for many years trying to figure out what movie this was from, you can probably understand just how hard it has been to try to Google this when I only remember a few scenes from the movie:

It was a college road trip sort of movie I believe where a class or group of students went on a trip with their teacher/s.

- In one scene the movies "fat and stupid" guy is bugging the leader/teacher who is talking to the receptionist at the place so either the leader or the receptionist takes a handful of candies/mints and throws on the ground behind them to make the fat guy run after it.
- In one scene the students have spiked the "hot teacher"s chocolate box with liquor to try to get her to strip in front of a two-way mirror, and one student is sent in to sort of seduce the drunk teacher.
- I believe there was one super creepy nerd who had a cardboard cutout of some actor who he worshiped.

I'm sorry to be so vague, we rented this movie on VHS so long ago and this is literally the only scenes I remember.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any  names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the movie National Lampoons **[Senior Trip](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113936)** 1995.

It stars a young Jeremy Renner in his first role!

There is a particularly creepy nerd who dresses up in a Star Trek uniform and has his own life size doll with him. There is also a heavyset fella in the same scene you describe at a hotel reception where sweets are thrown on the floor. At one point they get the female teacher drunk by injecting tequila into the chocolates.

Here is the trailer:

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend it was absolutely the right movie, i've been thinking about this one for over a decade now! :)

Comment: No worries! Glad it was the one you were looking for :)